# Why does ReSharper warn a function is used before it is declared?

Tags: javascript, resharper-9.0

I have written JavaScript code with a layout as seen below:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.doSomething(){
        someSubRoutine();
    }

    function someSubRoutine(){
        //Sub-routine code here
    }
}
```

ReSharper warns me that

> Function 'someSubRoutine' is used before it is declared

It is true that the function is used before it is declared, but is there an actual reason ReSharper is recommending I declare my function prior to usage? I figured due to JavaScript's hoisting abilities, this wouldn't be a problem. Should I be following this recommendation or just continue ignoring it?

Comment: Other than good coding practice and readable code, there is no actual reason (you won't have errors) as Javascript is parsed in whole (because the DOM is always fully traversed as a Markup language before being compiled)

Comment: ReSharper warns about a lot of things it shouldn't.  It's also particularly good at breaking entity queries so EF can't process them against a SQL data source at runtime.

Comment: There are a number of angular style guides (like [this one](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#services) that suggest doing it in the "bad practice" way for readability. Since most coding tools will take you to the function definition with a keyboard shortcut, it seems that in 2016 this rule is silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReSharper probably uses JSLint (or JSHint) under the hood, and these linting tools typically warn about that practice.

The issue boils down to a topic called "hoisting", which has been discussed heavily (for example, [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)). It's possible in some cases to use a method or variable before the JS interpreter has a chance to declare it... so the "best practice" is to declare somewhere above the first use.

**Edit:**
Here is an example where hoisting will cause possible unintended side effects:

```
var showState = function() {
    console.log("Idle");
};

function showState() {
  console.log("Ready");
} 

showState();            // output: Idle
```

This is because the JS interpreter uses hoisting to create the following during runtime:

```
function showState(){        // moved to the top (function declaration)
    console.log("Ready");
} 

var showState;               // moved to the top (variable declaration)

showState = function(){      // left in place (variable assignment)
    console.log("Idle");
};

showState();
```

Comment: The link provided does a great explanation and example to explain the case where a variable could be accessed before the JS interpreter has set  it equal to a function. In my case, it doesn't seem that someSubRoutine would ever be a problem because functions always get hoisted to the top. That said, I can chalk it up to ReSharper being overly careful and following good coding practices. I am going to add the example provided in the link to your answer to prevent it getting lost if the link is no longer available.

Comment: Resharper will then prompt you to combine the assignment and declaration.